# What is the reason for make a wallet with 1 token during ICO?

Tags: crowdsale

Because of my inexperience, I don't understand why (I guess for security reasons) contract owner of a crowdsale split its tokens over several owners, one of them with a 1 token only.

For example [Skraps](https://skraps.io/) has developed its ICO contract [here](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6e34d8d84764d40f6d7b39cd569fd017bf53177d) with a total supply tokens of 110M divided as below:

- 1st [owner](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6e34d8d84764d40f6d7b39cd569fd017bf53177d?a=0x8270e38651d6d4c867af7e8b1e8253469bd5c706) 109,499,999
- 2nd [owner](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6e34d8d84764d40f6d7b39cd569fd017bf53177d?a=0xc1028342293c78feadddb5b79e7d6de7be6e0c29) 500,000
- 3rd [owner](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6e34d8d84764d40f6d7b39cd569fd017bf53177d?a=0xfdaacc9935e7f02187986c59265270868b43a6ca) 1

> The ICO itself is a common ERC20 contract.

**What's the reason behind that owner who hold 1 token?**

[image]